# Adding JS to an existing HTML and CSS ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mern

so I already coded a chat app UI for my project site, after I learnt css and html, and now I want to add functionality to my existing code, and I don't know how to set up client server and add the chatting functions to my existing ui, every tutorial I come across is starting from the beginning, writing the code in react without using html files, any help?

Answer (score 0):

after learning html, css and javascript you should learn about javascript frameworks 
[you can do it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks) (for example react), you should start a new project.
You can start here [Create react app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)
You still need to try a little harder